# How to make IOS keyboard compact like YikYak or Vine

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uikeyboard

For now, i'm using the system default keyboard, and below is wat my keyboard looks like

```
_dummy = [UITextField new];
_dummy.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceLight;
_dummy.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
_dummy.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Here, the first screenshot is what my keyboard looks like, very old school, the next two are from YikYak and Vine.
[image: Screenshot from mine]
[image: Screenshot from YikYak]
[image: Screenshot from Vine]

The difference is obvious (i.e. The spacing, letter size). I want to make my keyboard as compact as Vine or YikYak's. Any thoughts?

Comment: The only difference between all the Keyboards is inputView, you can assign your own inputView to your `_dummy.inputView=<UIView>InputView;` See this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-creating-a-custom-text-input-view--mobile-15661

Comment: You're probably using iPhone 6 (plus). The cause of this is that your app is being rendered in zoomed mode. To make your app render your app in standard mode, I had to add a launch screen with the following name: "Default-667h@2x.png". I am not sure if that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, missing launch screen makes the iphone render in low-scale mode!